# How to trouble-shoot HDFStore Exception: cannot find the correct atom type

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am looking for some general guidance on what kinds of data scenarios can cause this exception.  I have tried massaging my data in various ways to no avail.

I have googled this exception for days now, gone through several google group discussions and come up with no solution to the debugging `HDFStore Exception: cannot find the correct atom type`.  I am reading in a simple csv file of mixed data types:

```
Int64Index: 401125 entries, 0 to 401124
Data columns:
SalesID                     401125  non-null values
SalePrice                   401125  non-null values
MachineID                   401125  non-null values
ModelID                     401125  non-null values
datasource                  401125  non-null values
auctioneerID                380989  non-null values
YearMade                    401125  non-null values
MachineHoursCurrentMeter    142765  non-null values
UsageBand                   401125  non-null values
saledate                    401125  non-null values
fiModelDesc                 401125  non-null values
Enclosure_Type              401125  non-null values
...................................................
Stick_Length                401125  non-null values
Thumb                       401125  non-null values
Pattern_Changer             401125  non-null values
Grouser_Type                401125  non-null values
Backhoe_Mounting            401125  non-null values
Blade_Type                  401125  non-null values
Travel_Controls             401125  non-null values
Differential_Type           401125  non-null values
Steering_Controls           401125  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(6), object(45)
```

Code to store the dataframe:

```
In [30]: store = pd.HDFStore('test0.h5','w')
In [31]: for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', chunksize=10000):
   ....:     store.append('df', chunk, index=False)
```

Note that if I use `store.put` on a dataframe imported in one shot, I can store it successfully, albeit slowly (I believe this is due to the pickling for object dtypes, even though the object is just string data).

Are there NaN value considerations that could be throwing this exception?

Exception:

```
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([Usa
geBand, saledate, fiModelDesc, fiBaseModel, fiSecondaryDesc, fiModelSeries, fiMo
delDescriptor, ProductSize, fiProductClassDesc, state, ProductGroup, ProductGrou
pDesc, Drive_System, Enclosure, Forks, Pad_Type, Ride_Control, Stick, Transmissi
on, Turbocharged, Blade_Extension, Blade_Width, Enclosure_Type, Engine_Horsepowe
r, Hydraulics, Pushblock, Ripper, Scarifier, Tip_Control, Tire_Size, Coupler, Co
upler_System, Grouser_Tracks, Hydraulics_Flow, Track_Type, Undercarriage_Pad_Wid
th, Stick_Length, Thumb, Pattern_Changer, Grouser_Type, Backhoe_Mounting, Blade_
Type, Travel_Controls, Differential_Type, Steering_Controls], dtype=object)] lis
t index out of range
```

**UPDATE 1**

Jeff's tip about lists stored in the dataframe led me to investigate embedded commas.  `pandas.read_csv` is correctly parsing the file and there are indeed some embedded commas within double-quotes.  So these fields are not python lists per se but do have commas in the text.  Here are some examples:

```
3     Hydraulic Excavator, Track - 12.0 to 14.0 Metric Tons
6     Hydraulic Excavator, Track - 21.0 to 24.0 Metric Tons
8       Hydraulic Excavator, Track - 3.0 to 4.0 Metric Tons
11      Track Type Tractor, Dozer - 20.0 to 75.0 Horsepower
12    Hydraulic Excavator, Track - 19.0 to 21.0 Metric Tons
```

However, when I drop this column from the pd.read_csv chunks and append to my HDFStore , I still get the same Exception.  When I try to append each column individually I get the following new exception:

```
In [6]: for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', header=0, chunksize=50000):
   ...:     for col in chunk.columns:
   ...:         store.append(col, chunk[col], data_columns=True)

Exception: cannot properly create the storer for: [_TABLE_MAP] [group->/SalesID
(Group) '',value-><class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>,table->True,append->True,k
wargs->{'data_columns': True}]
```

I'll continue to troubleshoot.  Here's a link to several hundred records:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AutqBaUiJLbPdHFvaWNEMk5hZ1NTNlVyUVduYTZTeEE&usp=sharing

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I tried the following on my work computer and got the following result:

```
In [4]: store = pd.HDFStore('test0.h5','w')

In [5]: for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', chunksize=10000):
   ...:     store.append('df', chunk, index=False, data_columns=True)
   ...:

Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([fiB
aseModel], dtype=object)] [fiBaseModel] column has a min_itemsize of [13] but it
emsize [9] is required!
```

I think I know what's going on here.  If I take the max length of the the field `fiBaseModel` for the first chunk I get this:

```
In [16]: lens = df.fiBaseModel.apply(lambda x: len(x))

In [17]: max(lens[:10000])
Out[17]: 9
```

And the second chunk:

```
In [18]: max(lens[10001:20000])
Out[18]: 13
```

So the store table is created with 9-bytes for this column because that's the maximum of the the first chunk.  When it encounters a longer text field in subsequent chunks, it throws the exception.

My suggestions for this would be to either truncate the data in subsequent chunks (with a warning) or allow the user to specify maximum storage for the column and truncate anything that exceeds it.  Maybe pandas can do this already, I haven't had time to truly dive deep into `HDFStore` yet.

**UPDATE 3**

Trying to import a csv dataset using pd.read_csv.  I pass a dictionary of all objects to the dtypes parameter.  I then iterate over the file and store each chunk into the HDFStore passing a large value for `min_itemsize`.  I get the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'itemsize'
```

My simple code:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test0.h5','w')
objects = dict((col,'object') for col in header)

for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', header=0, dtype=objects,
    chunksize=10000, na_filter=False):
    store.append('df', chunk, min_itemsize=200)
```

I've tried to debug and inspected the items in the stack trace.  This is what the table looks like at the exception:

```
ipdb> self.table
/df/table (Table(10000,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "values_block_0": StringCol(itemsize=200, shape=(53,), dflt='', pos=1)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (24,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}
```

**UPDATE 4**

Now I'm trying to iteratively determine the length of the longest string in object columns of my dataframe.  This is how I do it:

```
    def f(x):
        if x.dtype != 'object':
            return
        else:
            return len(max(x.fillna(''), key=lambda x: len(str(x))))

lengths = pd.DataFrame([chunk.apply(f) for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', chunksize=50000)])
lens = lengths.max().dropna().to_dict()

In [255]: lens
Out[255]:
{'Backhoe_Mounting': 19.0,
 'Blade_Extension': 19.0,
 'Blade_Type': 19.0,
 'Blade_Width': 19.0,
 'Coupler': 19.0,
 'Coupler_System': 19.0,
 'Differential_Type': 12.0
 ... etc... }
```

Once I have the dict of max string-column lengths, I try to pass it to `append` via the `min_itemsize` argument:

```
In [262]: for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', chunksize=50000, dtype=types):
   .....:     store.append('df', chunk, min_itemsize=lens)

Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([Usa
geBand, saledate, fiModelDesc, fiBaseModel, fiSecondaryDesc, fiModelSeries, fiMo
delDescriptor, ProductSize, fiProductClassDesc, state, ProductGroup, ProductGrou
pDesc, Drive_System, Enclosure, Forks, Pad_Type, Ride_Control, Stick, Transmissi
on, Turbocharged, Blade_Extension, Blade_Width, Enclosure_Type, Engine_Horsepowe
r, Hydraulics, Pushblock, Ripper, Scarifier, Tip_Control, Tire_Size, Coupler, Co
upler_System, Grouser_Tracks, Hydraulics_Flow, Track_Type, Undercarriage_Pad_Wid
th, Stick_Length, Thumb, Pattern_Changer, Grouser_Type, Backhoe_Mounting, Blade_
Type, Travel_Controls, Differential_Type, Steering_Controls], dtype=object)] [va
lues_block_2] column has a min_itemsize of [64] but itemsize [58] is required!
```

The offending column was passed a min_itemsize of 64, yet exception states an itemsize of 58 is required.  This may be a bug?

In [266]: pd.**version**
Out[266]: '0.11.0.dev-eb07c5a'

Comment: nan are ok, even in strings. the object types must be plain strings (and not anything else). show me a couple of rows I the actual data.

Comment: trouble shoot by trying the store the columns one at a time until u get a failure; the error message is the last field. pass data_columns=True to append (in practice you won't do this as u prob don't need to query on ALL the columns)

Comment: you have something besides strings in these columns, maybe a list?

Comment: Zelazny7, can you post your original file as well, I think I can make a better error message on storing failure...need a testcase. thanks

Comment: You can download the file here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-tqBaUiJLbPMHpaei1pcjlYdHM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: in regards to update 2, you can aprior-specify the itemsize upfront (on a per column or for all string columns, see my comment below in regards to dtype specification, same type of issue), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#notes-caveats

Comment: I will put on the enhance list to add 'itemsize=truncate', so subsequent appends will work (but obviously this will be user specified)...good idea! issue #13 on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2391

Comment: One more thing, I have an enhancement issue also open to allow something like 'create_table' so you can create your specification once (first), might be useful in cases like these

Comment: Thanks for your responses and guidance. The caveats sections was very helpful.  My main goal with HDFStore is to find a replacement for the SAS dataset.  Slowly, but surely, I'm getting there.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I've taken up enough of your time already. But if you have a chance, I would appreciate your comments regarding Update #3.

Comment: ok...that was a bug, thanks..after I update master, you can try again, but see my next comment

Comment: I would for sure specify your dtypes (and not object when they are numbers). Your file somewhere was parsing: ['SalesID', 'SalePrice', 'MachineID', 'ModelID', 'datasource', 'auctioneerID', 'YearMade'], rather than ['SalesID', 'SalePrice', 'MachineID', 'ModelID', 'datasource', 'auctioneerID', 'YearMade', 'MachineHoursCurrentMeter'] for int fields, in other words, the MachineHourseCurrentMeter must be nan somewhere (in the 2nd chunk or later), but 1st chunk shows it to be an int. You will get the exception "appended items do not match existing items in table!" when this is the case

Comment: The next logical extension of what I'm trying to do is determine the max length of object fields so I can pass a dict to min_itemsize of the append method.  I added update 4 with a possible bug.  Thanks.

Comment: this is not valid. you are telling it a particular column should have a minimum length, but all of the strings are in a single block, as u r not specifying data_columns (it is a bug that I let u specify this - and error msg should be better), you only can have a min per column if they are separate fields, otherwise the min is per column in a (same for each one) block. just use the min of the min (note that you are essentially looking thru your data twice in order to do this). better to just pick a reasonable number (separate issue is then we could allow u to truncate beyond that)

Comment: meant max of max! compression will generally deal with this anyhow

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3167 will provide an error for your code here (because you are trying to min_itemsize with a column that is not queryable). Also, you can use lib.max_len_string_array(s.values) for a quick max in your apply (faster and you don't need to test for object type)

Comment: Zelazny7 pls update to master and try this again

Comment: I have to wait until the dev binaries are pushed to the pydata website.  I have tried to build dev from source with no luck.  I spent much of the weekend troubleshooting the gcc errors when the binaries appeared on the site.  Yeah, windows...

Comment: ahh....for some reason thought you were on linux....get a VM! hopefully binaries will be soon...

Comment: I got the same error when I try to reproduce to example in pandas' doc [Storing Mixed Types in a Table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#storing-mixed-types-in-a-table). It works for put() but not for append(). I am using the 0.10.1 version from pip.

Comment: ... I forgot to mention I am using python2.7 on a linux64.

Comment: @Zelazny7 Did you try to run a random forest regression on your data? If so how did you proceed to pick random samples?

Comment: I didn't get it working with the HDFStore construct above, but I have sampled a dataframe in memory using this: `numpy.random.permutation(df.index)[:n_samps]`.  You could modify this to work on columns just as easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you provided worked just fine to store the frame. Column by column just means specifiy data_columns=True. It will process the columns individually and raise on the offending one.

To diagnose

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test0.h5','w')
In [31]: for chunk in pd.read_csv('Train.csv', chunksize=10000):
   ....:     store.append('df', chunk, index=False, data_columns=True)
```

In production, you probably want to restrict data_columns to the columns that you want to query (could be None as well, in which case you can query only on the index/columns)

Update:

You might run into another issue. read_csv converts dtypes based on what it sees in each chunk,
so with a chunksize of 10,000 the append operations failed because chunks 1 and 2 had
integer looking data in some columns, then in chunk 3 you had some NaN so it because floats.
Either specify upfront the dtypes, use a larger chunksize, or run your operations twice
to guarantee your dtypes between chunks.

I have updated pytables.py to have a more helpful exception in this case (as well
as telling you if a column has incompatible data)

thanks for the report!

Comment: What about the case with variable-length character data?

Comment: HDF5 doesn't support this in tables (you can do it via non-table though, e.g. put). Either make a big column (which works but could be inefficient space-wise), or segregate this data out and store via putting (of course then you have to deal with it when you query). see a suggestion here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3032

Comment: you might also take at look at the HDF5 section (renaming to HDFStore soon), here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html