# HDFStore Exception: cannot find the correct atom type : a basic case

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I am facing the same problem as the one raised in [How to trouble-shoot HDFStore Exception: cannot find the correct atom type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488809/how-to-trouble-shoot-hdfstore-exception-cannot-find-the-correct-atom-type).

I reduce it to an example given in the pandas' documentation [Storing Mixed Types in a Table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#storing-mixed-types-in-a-table).

The whole point in this example is to `append` a `DataFrame` with some missing values to a `HDFStore`. When I use the example code I end up with an `atom type error`.

```
df_mixed
Out[103]: 
          A         B         C  bool           datetime64  int  string
0 -0.065617 -0.062644 -0.004758  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
1  1.444643  1.664311 -0.189095  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
2  0.569412 -0.077504 -0.125590  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
3       NaN       NaN  0.563939  True                  NaN    1     NaN
4       NaN       NaN -0.618218  True                  NaN    1     NaN
5       NaN       NaN  1.477307  True                  NaN    1     NaN
6 -0.287331  0.984108 -0.514628  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
7 -0.244192  0.239775  0.861359  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string

store=HDFStore('df.h5')
store.append('df_mixed', df_mixed, min_itemsize={'values':50})

...
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([datetime64, string], dtype=object)] object of type 'Timestamp' has no len()
```

If I enforce `dtype` for the problematic types (actually the `object` ones) as suggested in the linked post (Jeff's answer), I still get the same error. What am I missing here?

```
dtypes = [('datetime64', '|S20'), ('string', '|S20')]

store=HDFStore('df.h5')
store.append('df_mixed', df_mixed, dtype=dtypes, min_itemsize={'values':50})

...
Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([datetime64, string], dtype=object)] object of type 'Timestamp' has no len()
```

Thanks for insights

**SOLVED**

I was using `pandas` 0.10 and switched to **0.11-dev** . As Jeff inferred, the trouble was with **NaN vs NaT**.

The former pandas version produced

```
df_mixed.ix[3:5,['A', 'B', 'string', 'datetime64']] = np.nan such that

2  0.569412 -0.077504 -0.125590  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
3       NaN       NaN  0.563939  True                  NaN    1     NaN
```

while the latter version

```
2  0.569412 -0.077504 -0.125590  True  2001-01-02 00:00:00    1  string
3       NaN       NaN  0.563939  True                  NaT    1     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the NaN in your datetime64[ns] series. These MUST be NaT. How did you construct this frame? What pandas version are you using?

Can you use 0.11-dev? (there are several more options here). Try this:

`df['datetime64'] = Series(df['datetime64'],dtype='M8[n2]')`

In addition, here are some more useful links: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore

Comment: you were right with upgrading to 0-11 to get the NaT right. I edited my post accordingly. Thanks