# pandas read_hdf with 'where' condition limitation?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I need to query an `HDF5` file with `where` clause with 3 conditions, one of the condition is a list with a length of 30:

```
myList = list(xrange(30))

h5DF   = pd.read_hdf(h5Filename, 'df', where='index=myList & date=dateString & time=timeString')
```

The query above gives me `ValueError: too many inputs` and the error is reproducible.

If I reduce length of the list to 29 (three conditions):

```
myList = list(xrange(29))

h5DF   = pd.read_hdf(h5Filename, 'df', where='index=myList & date=dateString & time=timeString')
```

**OR** number of conditions to only two (list length of 30):

then it executes fine:

```
myList = list(xrange(30))

h5DF   = pd.read_hdf(h5Filename, 'df', where='index=myList & time=timeString')
```

Is this a known limitation? pandas documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.pytables.read_hdf.html doesn't mention about this limitation and seems like after searching this forum nobody encounter this limitation yet.

Version is `pandas 0.15.2`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895837/hdfstore-table-select-and-ram-usage)

This is a defect in that `numpy/numexpr` cannot handle more than 31 operands in the tree. An expression like `foo=[1,2,3,4]` in the where of the `HDFStore` generates an expression like `(foo==1) | (foo==2) ....` so these are expanded and if you have too many can fail.

`HDFStore` handles this with a single operand (IOW if you just have `foo=[range(31)]` is ok, but because you happen to have a nested sub-expression where the sub-nodes themselves are too long it errors.

Generally a better way to do this is to select a bigger range (e.g. maybe the end-points of the selection for each operand), then do an in-memory `.isin`. It might even be faster, because HDF5 tends to be more efficient IMHO when selecting larger ranges (even though you are bringing more data to memory), rather than individual selections.