# Appending to HDFStore fails with "cannot match existing table structure"

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

The final solution was to use the "converters" parameter of read_csv and check every value before adding it to the DataFrame. In the end there were only 2 broken values in over 80GB of raw data.

The parameter looks like this:

```
converters={'XXXXX': self.parse_xxxxx}
```

And the small static helper method like this:

```
@staticmethod
def parse_xxxxx(input):
    if not isinstance(input, float):
        try:
            return float(input)
        except ValueError:
            print "Broken Value: ", input
            return float(0.0)
    else:
         return input
```

---

While trying to read ca. 40GB+ of csv data into a HDF file I ran into a confusing problem. After reading about 1GB the entire process fails with the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 658, in append
    self._write_to_group(key, value, table=True, append=True, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 923, in write_to_group
    s.write(obj = value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2985, in write **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2675, in create_axes
    raise ValueError("cannot match existing table structure for [%s] on appending data" % items)
ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for [Date] on appending data
```

The read_csv call I use is as follows:

```
pd.io.parsers.read_csv(filename, sep=";|\t", compression='bz2', index_col=False, header=None, names=['XX', 'XXXX', 'Date', 'XXXXX'], parse_dates=[2], date_parser=self.parse_date, low_memory=False, iterator=True, chunksize=self.input_chunksize, dtype={'Date': np.int64})
```

Why would the 'Date' column of the new chunk not fit the existing colum when Iexplicitly set the dtypte to int64?

Thx for your help!

Here is the function for parsing the date:

```
@staticmethod
def parse_date(input_date):
       import datetime as dt
       import re

       if not re.match('\d{12}', input_date):
           input_date = '200101010101'

        timestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
        return timestamp
```

After following some of Jeff's tips I can provide further details on my problem. Here is the entire code I use to load a bz2 encoded file:

```
iterator_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(filename, sep=";|\t", compression='bz2', index_col=False, header=None,
                                               names=['XX', 'XXXX', 'Date', 'XXXXX'], parse_dates=[2],
                                               date_parser=self.parse_date, iterator=True,
                                               chunksize=self.input_chunksize, dtype={'Date': np.int64})
for chunk in iterator_data:
    self.data_store.append('huge', chunk, data_columns=True)
    self.data_store.flush()
```

The csv file follows the following pattern: {STRING};{STRING};{STRING}\t{INT}

The output of *ptdump -av* called for the output file is the following:

```
ptdump -av datastore.h5
/ (RootGroup) ''
  /._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 4 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    PYTABLES_FORMAT_VERSION := '2.0',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0']
/huge (Group) ''
  /huge._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 14 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'GROUP',
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '1.0',
    data_columns := ['XX', 'XXXX', 'Date', 'XXXXX'],
    encoding := None,
    index_cols := [(0, 'index')],
    info := {'index': {}},
    levels := 1,
    nan_rep := 'nan',
    non_index_axes := [(1, ['XX', 'XXXX', 'Date', 'XXXXX'])],
    pandas_type := 'frame_table',
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',
    table_type := 'appendable_frame',
    values_cols := ['XX', 'XXXX', 'Date', 'XXXXX']]
/huge/table (Table(167135401,), shuffle, blosc(9)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "XX": StringCol(itemsize=16, shape=(), dflt='', pos=1),
  "XXXX": StringCol(itemsize=16, shape=(), dflt='', pos=2),
  "Date": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3),
  "XXXXX": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=4)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2340,)
  autoIndex := True
  colindexes := {
    "Date": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "XXXX": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "XXXXX": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False,
    "XX": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_CSI=False}
  /huge/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 23 attributes:
   [XXXXX_dtype := 'int64',
    XXXXX_kind := ['XXXXX'],
    XX_dtype := 'string128',
    XX_kind := ['XX'],
    CLASS := 'TABLE',
    Date_dtype := 'datetime64',
    Date_kind := ['Date'],
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := '',
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'XX',
    FIELD_2_FILL := '',
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'XXXX',
    FIELD_3_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_3_NAME := 'Date',
    FIELD_4_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_4_NAME := 'XXXXX',
    NROWS := 167135401,
    TITLE := '',
    XXXX_dtype := 'string128',
    XXXX_kind := ['XXXX'],
    VERSION := '2.6',
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

After a lot of additional debugging I got to the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid combinate of [values_axes] on appending data [name->XXXX,cname->XXXX,dtype->int64,shape->(1, 10)] vs current table [name->XXXX,cname->XXXX,dtype->string128,shape->None]
```

I then tried to fix this by adding modifying the *read_csv* call so to force the proper type for the XXXX column but just received the same error:

```
dtype={'XXXX': 's64', 'Date': dt.datetime})
```

Is *read_csv* ignoring the dtype settings or what am I missing here?

When reading the data with a chunksize of 10 the last 2 *chunk.info()* calls give the following output:

```
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
XX         10  non-null values
XXXX       10  non-null values
Date       10  non-null values
XXXXX      10  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(2)<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
XX         10  non-null values
XXXX       10  non-null values
Date       10  non-null values
XXXXX      10  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(1)
```

I'm using pandas version *0.12.0*.

Comment: well show the existing table and a sample of what u are trying to store (show df.info()), pandas version as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488809/how-to-trouble-shoot-hdfstore-exception-cannot-find-the-correct-atom-type might help u troubleshoot

Comment: also pls show won't exact code for reading and writing

Comment: also show ptdump -av <out.hdf>

Comment: I got a lot of additional information but read_csv seems to ignore the dtypes I set.

Comment: what is pandas version? show chunk.dtypes when it raises

Comment: I've added the version information and also the dtypes for the conflicting append.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok you have a couple of issues:

- when specifying dtypes to pass to `read_csv`, they must be numpy dtypes; and string dtypes are converted to `object` dtype (so the `s64` doesn't do anything). nor does the `datetime`, that's what `parse_dates` is used.
- your dtypes in different chunks are DIFFERENT, that is in the first on you have 2 `int64` columns and 1 `object`, while the 2nd has 1 `int64` and 2 `object`. This your problem. (I think the error message might be slightly confusing, which IIRC is fixed in later versions of pandas).

So, you need to conform your dtypes in EVERY chunk to be the same. You might have mixed data in that particular column. One way to do this is to specify `dtype = { column_that_is_bad : 'object' }`. Another is to use `convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` ON THAT column to coerce all non-numeric values to `nan` (this will also change the dtype of the column to `float64`).

Comment: Even after changing the dtype to: dtype={'XX': 'object', 'XXXX': 'object', 'Date': 'object', 'XXXXX': 'uint64'}) upgrading to Pandas 0.13.1 I get this:
ValueError: invalid combinate of [values_axes] on appending data [name->XXXXX,cname->XXXXX,dtype->float64,shape->(1, 10000000)] vs current table [name->XXXXX,cname->XXXXX,dtype->int64,shape->None]

Comment: you need to conform the dtypes before you write them to HDF, look at df.dtypes of each chunk before you are writing them. some data is change them (e.g. you may have missing values in one but not in another). You need to coerce to the proper format.

Comment: Mixed dtypes was my issue as well. This confusing error message still exists as of pandas 0.20.3 for hdf