# Python - Using a MSSQL data source with pandas and HDFStore

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm somewhat new to python and pandas, but have been playing with R for awhile. From some early tests that I've been playing with, I'm really excited to move a lot of what I have been doing in R into python as the language is much easier to work with. However, I'm  running into a few issues with the way pandas handles SQL data.

Our company collects lots and lots of data. I'm using one table that we have to try and analyze the probability that a potential customer will purchase a product. This table has 9 million rows with each row representing a customer. There is an inquiry number, some customer information, what product he was interested in, the price of the product, and whether it was purchased. The table is stored in Microsoft SQL Server.

I've been able to play with smaller subsets of this data by bringing it out of SQL and into pandas datasets. I've been been able to fit models using scikit-learn. But a few things have been frustrating me.

I'd like to be able to save the pandas datasets after I've downloaded them from the server. I think that will allow me to take better advantage of the limited memory available to me. My impression is that HDF is the best way to do this because it is integrated into the pandas library. However I've run into a few frustrating items. Because I don't have super amazing hardware, I have to chunk the results from the SQL server to save. Unfortunately, I have null values in some of my integer columns. [Pandas doesn't support nan's in integer series as part of some design decisions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html), so it gets upconverted to float64. The problem is that when chunking, some of the chunks won't have nan's and some will, so the chunks will have differing datatypes. This causes problems when trying to append the chunks into HDFStore dataset. So what is best practice when dealing with data like this in a memory-constrained world? Should I write code to test for the best datatype for each column, then convert each column within a chunk to that datatype before saving to the HDF store?

Alternatively, what is the best practice for taking a bug MSSQL table and converting it into something which is more python friendly? should I avoid that at all costs? Should I just keep SQL tables formatted so that I won't run into problems like the above? What are the best practices you've uncovered to deal with these types of issues?

Thanks.

Comment: See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488809/how-to-trouble-shoot-hdfstore-exception-cannot-find-the-correct-atom-type. If you have an 'integer' column that *can* have a nan, simply convert to float upfront.

Comment: Thanks. In one of the comments, its suggested that you run the chunking twice. First time to detect the right datatype and then again to actually save it. I like this approach. Is there logic built into pandas that I can use that help me manage the promotions efficiently, or would I have to built my own promotion tree, test each chunk for the best datatype, and somehow merge the detected chunks dtype to the prior dtype and promote as needed? What's best practice for this?

Comment: Here's a nice way to do this: http://blaze.pydata.org/docs/latest/index.html